# Type or Namespace 't' could not be found in lambda clearly defining t

Tags: c#, types, lambda, intellisense

```
public static bool Is(this object o, IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
    return types.Any(t => o is t);
}
```

It's a simple extension method to test whether an object is one of the provided types - used to make code more readable.

Anyway it says it can't find what `t` is (the second instance of `t`). It's pretty clearly defined right before its use in the lambda function, and hovering over the first instance of it *Intellisense* even tells me that it's *(parameter)* `Type t`.

Pretty confused about this, since I don't know why VS can't figure it out. Occasionally *Intellisense* acts up and restarting VS will fix it, but not this time.

(BTW, this is VS2013)

Edit: I disagree with this being a duplicate. The question comes from a totally different angle and has a different accepted answer.

Comment: Tried that already, doesn't help.

Comment: `return types.Any(t => o is Type);`

Comment: `return types.Any(t => o.GetType() == t);`

Comment: Try  types.any(t => o.GetType() == t)

Comment: I appreciate the help but the issue is that Intellisense doesn't seem to SEE that 't' exists, so changing the ways we test it isn't going to change that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `is` operator requires an object on the left and a *type name* on the right. A literal type *name*, not an instance of class System.Type.

From your code, I guess that what you want to do is check if a certain object is an instance of some type represented by its System.Type. In this case, you need to use the [IsInstanceOfType method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype(v=vs.110).aspx) of class Type

```
return types.Any(t => t.IsInstanceOfType(o));
```

Comment: I think this is precisely what I want - thanks. I'm curious why the error message generated by Intellisense was so generic, though. It clearly wasn't because it couldn't find 't', but that's what it told me.

Comment: See comments on the other answer if you are curious why the error was what it was.

Comment: @Yushatak - "It clearly wasn't because it couldn't find 't'" - no, it couldn't find a *Type* or a *Namespace* within the current context. It didn't bother mentioning the `t` that was there since that was a variable, and it wasn't looking for one of those.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `o is t` is that `t` needs to be a type not an variable holding a type. Instead you can do this:

```
return types.Any(t => o.GetType() == t);
```

Or:

```
return types.Any(t => t.IsInstanceOfType(o));
```

This will ensure that the types are an exact match. If you care about types that inherit from other types, then this is more accurate:

```
return types.Any(t => o.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

Comment: That first method doesn't help. This isn't because t isn't an actual type name (not that it's impossible that that is *also* a problem) it's because Intellisense can't find t at all.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: "The type or namespace name 't' could not be found (are you missing a using  directive or assembly reference?)" - the below answer solves it (they got the acceptance since they were first) but I'm still confused as to why that's what Intellisense reported.

Comment: It's not intellisense, it's the actual error you get when you try to us `is` because the compiler is looking for a type called "t".

Comment: Ah that makes sense - I still feel it should have been identified as a less generic scenario and given a clearer error, myself, but at least I know where it was coming from now.

Comment: I'm not sure the error message could be any clearer though, it's telling you it can't find a type called t

Comment: How about "The 'is' keyword cannot operate on objects of type 'Type', and must be passed the name of a type directly."

Comment: That error relates to the is keyword though, not the type name. Note that the error is used in more than just this one place. For example, `typeof(t)` will probably give the same message.

Comment: Yes, I agree - I think that it should have been caught by an assertion or other check somewhere before it got that far and was caught by a generic message, though. The fact that I've seen that message hundreds of times for very different reasons is exactly why I didn't interpret it properly in this context - typically it is when something is out of scope or namespace and I knew it wasn't, here. If you disagree, then to each their own.

Comment: Well at least I didn't waste my time writing this answer!